# Moving a field of data in one table to another table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am currently trying to add a field from one table into another table.

In my example code, I have the competitor ID in the individuals table (this is also the primary key). But i want this ID to appear in another table called Individual events but I am stuck on how to do this. I think I have made this the foreign key in my individual events table

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see my code below (it should run and work, but no result regarding the field displaying in the individual events table)

```
def create_database():
    global cursor
    global connection
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Tournament.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

def create_tables():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE tblIndividuals
(competitorID INTEGER,
title TEXT,
firstName TEXT,
surname TEXT,
primary key (competitorID))
""")

def menu():
    select = int (input("Please select from the following options....\n "
                   "1. Add a team or individual\n "
                   "2. Start the individual events\n "
                   "3. Start the team events\n "))
    if select == 1:
        add_entry()
    if select == 2:
        individual_events()

def add_entry():

    type_of_entry = input("Individual or team entry? ")

    competitor_numbers_used = []
    record = []

    while type_of_entry == "individual":

        global competitorID
        competitorID = random.randint(1,20)
        competitor_numbers_used.append(competitorID)

        if competitorID in competitor_numbers_used:
            competitorID = random.randint(1,20)

        title = input ("Enter your title: ")
        firstName = input("Enter your first name: ")
        surname = input("Enter surname: ")

        record.append(competitorID)
        record.append(title)
        record.append(firstName)
        record.append(surname)

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tblIndividuals VALUES (?,?,?,?)", record)
        record = []
        connection.commit()
        type_of_entry = input("Individual or team entry? (Type end to go back to the menu) ")
        if type_of_entry == "end":
            menu()

def individual_events():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE tblIndividualEvents
(competitorID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(competitorID) REFERENCES tblIndividuals(competitorID))
"""                 

create_database()
create_tables()
menu()

connection.close
```

Comment: This is way too much code, Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, thank you for letting me know (I'm new to this), I've shortened it as much as possible. I just need that competitorID(in the table Individuals) to appear in another table called IndividualEvents.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken any action to add data to the second table. Creating a second table with the same field name doesn't affect the data in the second table.

Things you could do:

1. When you insert values into the first table, manually insert the same value into the second table.
2. After you've inserted all values into the first table, bulk insert all values into the second table via an `INSERT INTO ... (SELECT ...)`
3. Create an insert trigger on the first table that responds to inserts there by inserting the same value in the second table.

Bottom line, defining the structure of the second table does not cause any data to be added to it.